# covert the xml data to Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Could any one help me to convert  the below data to table format.

```
<people>      
    <person>         
        <name>John Doe</name>     
        <age>21</age>         
    </person>        
    <person>             
        <name>Jane Smith</name>             
        <age>24</age>        
        </person>    
</people>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get the data from the XML. You can use the query as a source for the insert statement to a table.

```
declare @xml xml = 
'<people>      
    <person>         
        <name>John Doe</name>     
        <age>21</age>         
    </person>        
    <person>             
        <name>Jane Smith</name>             
        <age>24</age>        
    </person>    
</people>'

select T.X.value('name[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Name,
       T.X.value('age[1]', 'int') as Age      
from @xml.nodes('/people/person') as T(X)
```

Result:

```
Name                                               Age
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
John Doe                                           21
Jane Smith                                         24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try XSLT to style your xml data.
Save this astest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<people>      
    <person>         
        <name>John Doe</name>     
        <age>21</age>         
    </person>        
    <person>             
        <name>Jane Smith</name>             
        <age>24</age>        
        </person>    
</people>
```

Save this into test.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="people/person">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="age"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then drag the xml into IE to see the result.

Comment: Since the question has a "sql-server-2008" tag, I assume the OP wants to extract the data into a **database** table - not an HTML table...